# Select insert query loop

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Hi I am new to java I am wanted to repeat this insert query for 4 times so that total rows will be 500 but I dont know how to start if anyone can guide me or help me i will really appreciate thank you

in my db in tbl_1 I have 100 rows
like this

```
    id       username       password
     1          a              adk
     2         dj              jsjsj
     3         jddk            kdkkd
     .....until id is 100
     .
     .
     100       jdjdj           jdjjdj
```

I want to insert in the same table but will insert the id start the id to 101  until id is 500 my query is working but inserting same data and same id'same

expected output

```
   id       username       password
   1          a              adk
   2         dj              jsjsj
   3         jddk            kdkkd
    .....until id is 100
    .
    .
   100       jdjdj           jdjjdj
   101          a              adk
   102         dj              jsjsj
   103         jddk            kdkkd
   .....until id is 200
   .
   .
   200       jdjdj           jdjjdj
   till reach 500


   import java.sql.*;


 public class insertsql
 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  try
{

 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
  Connection connection =     
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:;databaseName=;    

user=;password=;");


  Statement st = connection.createStatement();

  st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tbl_1 (id, username,password)\n" +
 "SELECT a.id,a.username,a.password\n" +
 "FROM tbl_1 a");

  connection.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception!");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}

  }
 }
```

Comment: `initialize counter = 0;
while counter < 5 
//do insert
//increment counter by 1`

Comment: but can i ask for the id to start to insert to 101 and to end  500 will i used the counter thank you really appreciate your help

Comment: you can have the ID column as PK and set autoincrement no need to use the variable counter as value of that column. also counter counts only until 4. as mention above you already have the insert to 100.

Comment: i understand thank you very much

Comment: im glad it worked happy coding